# How can I run a function in the terminal of VS Code for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and VS Code and was having a lot of trouble trying to run my code. My code is trying to iterate through every other number in an array backwards, what I have so far is:

```
const myArray = []
 function validateCred(myArray) {
     for (var i = valid1.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
         let everyOtherNumber = valid1.filter((element, index) => {
             return index % 2 === 0;
           })
     }
 }
```

The code needs work since it does not actually give me every other number, but the problem I was not able to run it in my terminal. Without the function `validateCred()`, I am able to run the code just fine by typing `node main.js` in the terminal, but when I put that for loop in the function, it does not work anymore, and trying things like `node main.js validateCred()` don't work. Basically I don't know how to run this code.

Comment: you are not calling the function.

Comment: You need to first of all call validateCred by using validateCred(myArray); and then you will likely need to change "valid1" to myArray.

Comment: And you are not `return`ing anything in the `validateCred` function, not logging anything either, so you won't see anything in the terminal

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking on the check mark. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the function after declaring it:

```
function validateCred(myArray) {
     // code for validateCred(myArray) function
 }

// call the function with your array
validateCred(myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call your function by passing value.

```
const myArray = []
 function validateCred(myArray) {
     for(var i = array.length; i--;){
        //your code here
     }
     return;
 }

//now call your function with values
validateCred(myArray);
```

Now you do `node <filename>`. This way you can run your file from VSCode terminal.